# Build a generic `map` like function in cpp

Tags: c++, templates

Consider

```
template <typename S, typename T, typename F>
vector<T> map(const vector<S> &ss, F f){
    vector<T> ts;
    ts.reserve(ss.size());
    std::transform(ss.begin(), ss.end(), std::back_inserter(ts), f);
    return ts;
}

int main(){
    vector<int> is = {...};
    vector<double> ts = map(is, [](int i){return 1.2*i;});
}
```

because the compiler  'couldn't deduce template parameter T'. Specifying `map` of type

```
template <typename S, typename T>
vector<T> map(const vector<S> &ss, std::function<T(S)> f)
```

also doesn't work, because it doesn't match lambdas.

What's the correct way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this:

```
template <typename S, typename F>
auto map(const std::vector<S> &ss, F f) -> std::vector<std::decay_t<decltype(f(ss[0]))>>
{
    std::vector<std::decay_t<decltype(f(ss[0]))>> ts;
    ts.reserve(ss.size());
    std::transform(ss.begin(), ss.end(), std::back_inserter(ts), std::move(f));
    return ts;
}
```

I've opted for a trailing return type, to be able to use `f` and `ss` in `decltype`. You could just use `auto` return type, but explicitly specifying the type makes the function SFINAE-friendly.

---

Or, a slightly overengineered version with hottest C++20 features:

```
template <
    template <typename...> typename C = std::vector,
    typename S, typename F
>
[[nodiscard]] C<std::decay_t<std::indirect_result_t<F, std::ranges::iterator_t<S>>>>
map(S &&ss, F f)
{
    C<std::decay_t<std::indirect_result_t<F, std::ranges::iterator_t<S>>>> ts;
    ts.reserve(std::ranges::size(ss));
    std::ranges::transform(ss, std::back_inserter(ts), std::move(f));
    return ts;
}
```

Comment: I'll buy the one that I do understand :).

Comment: @Bubaya Basically the second one allows you to call the function like `auto ts = map<std::vector>(is, [](int i) {return 1.2 * i; });`

Answer (score 2):

this works

```
  std::vector<double> ts = map<int, double>(is, [](int i) {return 1.2 * i; });
```